# In TYPO3 6.1, how to configure CSC content fallback only for images

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

In a dual-language (single-tree) TYPO3 6.1, I have a completely regular texpic content element.

TSConfig: `mod.web_layout.defLangBinding = 1`

TypoScript:

```
config.sys_language_overlay =1

temp.lead < styles.content.get
temp.lead.select.where = colPos = 2
```

How can I tell css_styled_content to use the image from the main language if no other image is specified?

Setting `config.sys_language_mode = content_fallback` won't help, as we only want images to fall back, no Text.

The original image is appearing in the localised record, but greyed out:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a slightly hidden button to the right of that entry that editors  can use to localise that file reference:

[image]

Once localised, the reference works as expected.